# What are 'herbycall verses'?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word, early-modern-english

This [line in Philotimus](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/pageviewer-idx?cc=eebo2;c=eebo2;idno=a07415.0001.001;node=A07415.0001.001:5.5;seq=131;vid=10522;page=root;view=text), specifically the word ‘herbycall’, has been perplexing me:

> Herewithall she yelded breath. Great mourninges were ex∣cited in euery corner, and wofull Philotimus swounding thrée or foure times, could scarcely be relieued with life, who in time re∣couered a litle, **compiled these herbycall verses,** to bewaile his owne and his sisters piteous plight now left desolate.

In modern orthography, this is basically:

> Herewithall she yielded breath. Great mournings were excited in every corner, and woeful Philotimus [swounding](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swounding) three or four times, could scarcely be relieved with life, who in time recovered a little, **compiled these herbycall verses,** to bewail his own and his sisters' piteous plight now left desolate.

‘Herbycall’ doesn’t appear in any Google Books search, anywhere else in the book, or online, as far as I've found.

I can think of two possibilities, though neither of them seems particularly promising:

- ‘herbycall’ is ‘herbical,’ which a few older books use as a synonym for ‘herbal.’ Doesn’t make sense, though.
- ‘herbycall’ is a compound, probably either ‘her-by-call’ or ‘hereby-call.’ I assume that such compounds were common in those days  (Philotimus is full of them, at least), but I still can’t think of what either of these could mean, especially in this context.

So does anyone else have any theory or insights as to what on earth ‘herbycall’ means?

(I can’t find a photo version of the original text, so I have no idea if this is a mistranscription)

Comment: The nearby use of 'Herewithall' probably points to your second theory, with _herewith_ part of the compound.

Comment: Could it be a mis-reading of 'heroicall'?

Comment: Are these verses referred to elsewhere in the text?

Comment: @alphabet - no, they aren't. (can't find them anywhere else online, either)

Comment: @Heartspring I'm wondering if the following few sentences ("When roote is old...protector") might *be* the verses in question (they're almost metrical and certainly poetic). "Herbycall" then might mean something like "following."

Comment: @alphabet - yes, those are definitely the verses. [Here's](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A07415.0001.001/1:5.5?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=When+roote+is+old) a prettier version; you have to scroll down about halfway through the page or use ctrl+f. (And yes, you could be right.)

Comment: Maybe "herbycall"/"herbical" is a euphemism for saying he was stoned when he came up with those verses. Just a thought. I mean, 'herb' is a slang term for cannabis. Maybe it goes back that far, or maybe it used to be a term for it and became a term for it again out of obviousness.

Comment: I suggest you go to a library and find a text, or buy one online, rather than post a series of similar questions that could easily be answered by the correct reference.

Comment: @StuartF - I didn't think it would be in a library since it's so old but turns out that it is. I was able to get the answer to this question, but the other one remains a mystery for now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Although there is some variation, these "heroical" verses seem generally to be made up of four iambs and two amphibrachs: How **can** | a **blind** | man **goe** | with**out** | some **guid** for | his **ayd**er? This is a meter that I've never seen, but for which I certainly wouldn't object to the term "heroycal".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is predicated on a misprint, if the most sensible theory is valid.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — But *herbycall* so captures the imagination; it’s worth it just to keep it around.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That would be basing the question's closure on an answer, not on the merits of the question itself. I respectfully disagree, and VTLO :)

Comment: I'm with [Greybeard](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15567/is-there-a-need-for-an-addition-to-the-reasons-for-closing-for-questions-that) here. The answer is that the question refers to a typo, and this answer has been given before to like questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that "heroycall" (in modern English "heroical") was meant (as Kate Bunting proposed in a comment above), with the "o" simply miswritten as "b". This could have meant "having to do with heroism" but more likely referred to "heroic verse". I couldn't find the following verses in your link, so I couldn't verify that they were actual written in heroic verse, but that term apparently [had various definitions in late 16th century Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroic_verse) (as it does today).

EDIT: Heartspring has found a scan of what is apparently the original hardcopy text:

[image]

The letter in question appears to be an "o" with some "static" that may have been mistaken for an ascender, either by a person or by [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition). One can see an actual "b" a few words later, in "bewaile".

Comment: I'd say you're right; I got access to the original text and it seems to be a scanning error. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wa6C.png) a screenshot of that line. [Here](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A07415.0001.001/1:5.5?rgn=div2;submit=Search;subview=detail;type=simple;vid=10522;view=fulltext;q1=herbycall#hl1) are the verses themselves, if you'd like to confirm.

Comment: @Heartspring — Yes, and you can see a proper *b* just to the right in *bewaile*.

Comment: @Heartspring Thank you! I've incorporated that into the answer.